# mysql varbinary vs varchar

Tags: mysql, character, collation

We use varchar(255) for storing "keywords" in mysql. We are facing a problem that mysql ignores all trailing spaces for comparison purposes in "=". It does respect trailing spaces in "like" comparison, but it does not let us store same word with and without trailing spaces in a varchar column if it has a "UNIQUE" index over it.

So, we are considering switching to varbinary. Can anybody suggest what could be the implications when there are multi-byte characters in column values?

Answer (score 2):

Andomar,

We use version 5.0.5. All mysql versions ignore trailing spaces for comparison. From the manual:

> All MySQL collations are of type
>   PADSPACE. This means that all CHAR and
>   VARCHAR values in MySQL are compared
>   without regard to any trailing spaces.
>   This is true for all MySQL versions,
>   and it makes no difference whether
>   your version trims trailing spaces
>   from VARCHAR values before storing
>   them

Moreover mysql considers texts with/without trailing spaces duplicate in indexes:

> For those cases where trailing pad
>   characters are stripped or comparisons
>   ignore them, if a column has an index
>   that requires unique values, inserting
>   into the column values that differ
>   only in number of trailing pad
>   characters will result in a
>   duplicate-key error. For example, if a
>   table contains 'a', an attempt to
>   store 'a ' causes a duplicate-key
>   error.

And, we absolutely need an index on keywords.
So, I guess we have two options: varbinary or text. We shall evaluate the performance of "text", and multibyte functionality for varbinary.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html) says about trailing spaces:

> Handling of trailing spaces is
>   version-dependent. As of MySQL 5.0.3,
>   trailing spaces are retained when
>   values are stored and retrieved, in
>   conformance with standard SQL. Before
>   MySQL 5.0.3, trailing spaces are
>   removed from values when they are
>   stored into a VARCHAR column; this
>   means that the spaces also are absent
>   from retrieved values.

Since your question says that MySQL does not repsect trailing spaces, I assume your version is lower than 5.0.3.  Consider using the TEXT type for your column; these preserve trailing spaces.  TEXT will handle the string's [encoding and decoding](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) for you, so you don't have to worry about multi-byte characters.

TEXT does perform slower than VARBINARY.  If actual data shows that performance is unacceptable, you might have to opt for VARBINARY (or a BLOB.)  In that case, it's up to you to store the string in a particular encoding, like [UTF-8](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).  As long as all your clients use the same encoding, this would work fine for multi-byte characters.  Do test your clients with different regional settings :)

Comment: This answer is somewhat misleading as it misses the consquences for UNIQUE indexes completely. See ashweta's own answer for more info

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the trailing space problem, your UNIQUE INDEX in MySQL will be limited to 767 bytes (which makes 767/3 ~= 255 for 3-byte UTF8).  See also:

- http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=4541
- http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=42193
- http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9431