# How to read IPv6 address stored as a varbinary in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ipv6, varbinary

I am storing IPv6 addresses as a `varbinary` with PHP function `inet_pton($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])`. When I run an SQL query such as:

```
SELECT ip_address FROM some_table WHERE id='some_id';
```

I wouldn't be able to read the ip_address because it is in a `binary` format.

I notice that there is a corresponding MySQL function `INET6_NTOA(expr)` in [MySQL version 5.6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet6-ntoa) to revert it back to readable format. Unfortunately, I am using MySQL version 5.5, which doesn't have that function.

Is there any other way I can read the IPv6 addresses without going back to PHP to do the conversion? I can easily read off the hexadecimal notation of the binary string with the editor in the Workbench as shown in the image attached, so I thought there should be an easy way to do this.

[image]

Comment: read similar : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873085/how-to-convert-from-varbinary-to-char-varchar-in-mysql

Comment: also see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973923/mysql-varbinary-vs-varchar and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420680/how-to-store-ipv6-compatible-address-in-a-relational-database

Comment: @diEcho, I have tried `cast` and `convert`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You can write user-defined functions to do the conversion for you and call them in the select clause. See [this](http://labs.watchmouse.com/2009/10/extending-mysql-5-with-ipv6-functions/) link for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Is there a way to read off the hexadecimal notation that I see with "open value in editor" on the MySQL workbench?